# How to represent Big O(n!) Time complexity from for loop?

Tags: big-o, factorial

For Example

O(n)

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
```

After Edit : My Final Answer is

```
for(int i =(n - 1); i > 1; i--)
 {
         factorial = factorial * i;             
 }  
 for (int j=n-2;j<factorial;j++)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is
    for (int i = 0; i < Factorial(n); i++) {...

In practice, usually O(n!) algorithms are those that work by trying all the different permutations of a list, that is, all the different ways you can reorder a list. One example is finding the shortest line that passes through all points in a map called the travelling salesman problem. You need to try all the different ways to go through all the points and that would be O(n!).

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> nextPermutation(List<int> nodesLeft)
{
    if (nodesLeft.Count == 0)
    {
        yield return new List<int>();
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodesLeft.Count; i++)
        {
            List<int> newNodesLeft = new List<int>(nodesLeft);
            newNodesLeft.removeAt(i);

            foreach (List<int> subPermutation in nextPermutation(newNodesLeft)
            {
                subPermutation.add(nodesLeft[i]);
                yield return subPermutation;
            }
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    foreach (List<int> permutation in nextPermutation(new List<int>(new int[]{1,2,3,4,5}))) {
        //every permutation of [1,2,3,4,5] will be generated here
        //this will take O(n!) to complete, where n is the number of nodes given (5 in this case)
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to click the very good sign on the side if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

If recursion is allowed then:

```
void loop(int n)
{
    if(n == 1) 
        return; // the program gets here exactly n! times

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        loop(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fact = 1;
for( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
{
    fact = fact*c;
}
```

like this?

Answer (score 0):

If we're on the same page here... I think that would look like..
`Tau(fetch) + Tau(store) + (2Tau(fetch) + Tau(<) )*(N + 1) + (2Tau(fetch) + Tau(+) + Tau(store)) * N`